# How do you create a TimePicker like the default Android clock app?

Tags: android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CrAD.jpg

Here is a screenshot of the timepicker that I want. Just a line of a time and PM or AM option. There are arrows to the top and bottom of the times and you can easily set the time. I want to build something like this in my app but the TimePicker xml file does not show this. How did Android build this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's unlikely that it would be possible. Based on the looks of the
TimePicker, it is from TouchWiz, made by Samsung. Unless that code is open source, it would not be possible to use that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if Samsung can make it, someone else can too. After all this is just a collection of well-chosen ui elements that make this widget.

Comment: @Elijan9 that's true.